# R - overcoming memory limitations when generating 'interaction variables'

Tags: r, bigdata

I would like to run a regularised regression (e.g. lasso). My dataset contains 50k observations and 500 variables (x1, x2, ... x500).

I am attempting to generate a matrix capturing all possible interactions terms between each of my x variables (that is, x1*x2, x1*x3... x499*n500). I recognise this will be a very large matrix (42k rows, 125k columns) and given my variables are continuous, I will not be able to store as a sparse matrix. The code I have been using to generate this matrix is:

```
x_interactions <- model.matrix(~.^2, data=x)
```

Unfortunately it appears R cannot store this amount of data in the memory on my machine and I receive an error message after 15 mins of execution informing me that I have run out of RAM.

My question is this: (1) Is there a more efficient way to generate this matrix that can be achieved without breaching the RAM limits, or 
(2) Is there a package that can run the calculations using graphics memory or some other method to overcome the memory limitations?

Comment: What are you planning to do with your matrix? I doubt that you could keep such a huge object in memory.

Comment: I plan on using it for lasso regression using the glmnet package, but this will also no doubt pose memory challenges.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/five-ways-to-handle-big-data-in-r/